# C return value is displaying some bizarre behavior

Tags: c, return-value

A fair warning — I'm very new to C, and there's some unpredictable behavior. I'm not sure how to begin troubleshooting this.

I'm trying to solve one of the early Euler problems (to do with numerical palindromes) and I'm having trouble with my check function. When a number `a` is passed through `rev(a)`, everything works as it should. When passed through `ret(a)` (a function which will eventually check for equality, bool type, etc), it returns totally wrong number — something to do with memory, I think. Can anybody help me, please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int rev(int a);
int check(int a);

main() {
    int a = 12;
    printf("%i ", a);
    printf("%i ", rev(a));
    printf("%i\n", ret(a));
}

int ret(int a){
    return rev(a);
}

int rev(int a){
    int b;
    while (a>0){
        b = (b*10) + a%10;
        a/=10;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: If you think there's _something to do with memory_ going on, it's probably worth looking at valgrind. It can often show you the problem.

Comment: This isn't a memory thing, though.  (Well, except insofar as local variables typically reside in RAM.)  The program's not doing anything that'd cause memory issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `rev`, the first iteration of the loop

```
int b;
while (a>0){
    b = (b*10) + a%10;
```

operates on an uninitialised value of `b`.  This makes the end result unpredictable and almost  certainly wrong.

The fix is pretty simple - you just need to initialise `b` to 0

```
int rev(int a){
    int b = 0;
    // function unchanged beyond this
```

If calls to `rev` worked for you, this was just luck (either good or bad, depending how you look at it).  Reading the content of uninitialised memory can have any effect, including  the stack for `b` just happening to be set to 0.  You'd probably have found that changing platform or compiler flags caused things to break.

Comment: Note also, things might get really dicey if `a` is negative.  (-1 / 10 == -1 in most languages i've worked with.)  It should probably be declared as `unsigned`.

Comment: This is exactly the problem! Thank you so much, simonc!

Comment: @cHao That is surprising. It was implementation-defined (iirc, could have been unspecified, but I'd be surprised) in C prior to C99, but as of C99, `-1/10` must be 0. It's also 0 in Java. In which languages was it `-1`?

Comment: I forget, actually, and i can't seem to replicate it at the moment.  I just remember having run into it a number of times.  It caught me out often enough that i'm now a bit paranoid when i see it.  :P

Comment: Ahh.  Here we go.  It's -1 in Python and Ruby.

Comment: @cHao Thanks. Wow, I guess I'm lucky that I never fell into that trap when using Python.

Comment: @DanielFischer: It's kinda a trap either way.  I'm starting to remember where my paranoia about C came from:  In the languages where -1/10 == 0, -1 *mod* 10 == -1.  That's probably fine in this case (since every 'digit' is actually going to be negative; you'll just wind up with a negative number with the digits reversed).  But it's incredibly annoying when you're trying to use the modulus to keep numbers between 0 and some limit.

Comment: @cHao Yes, that is true. It would be easier to deal with if all languages behaved the same.